# Visual Studio C# Solution with many Projects (Dependencies)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a c# WebAPI Application that has the following structure[image]

The Solution has many Projects, The core Project which is the actual WebAPI project and more than one separate projects that are used for communication with external systems.
My Project uses dependency Injection like this:
The core Project might have in its web config defined an external system.
When the various dependencies are registered there exists a code like this

```
string ExternalSystem = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExternalService"];
switch(ExternalSystem)
            {
                case "ExtA":
                    this.RegisterType<ExtA.ExternalService>().As<IExternalService>().InstancePerRequest();
                    break;
                case "ExtB":
                    this.RegisterType<ExtB.ExternalService>().As<IExternalService>().InstancePerRequest();
                    break;
                default:
                    this.RegisterType<ExternalService>().As<IExternalService>().InstancePerRequest();
                    break;
            }
```

The definition of IExternalService is in the Core Project and each of the Extrnal Systems has it's own Implementation of this Interface.
So the decision on which of the implementations is going to be used is defined in the web config file in the Core Project.
This implemantation has one problem. When I create my release dlls, I have to include all external system's Dlls (even if they are not used), otherwise 
lines of code like this

```
this.RegisterType<ExtA.ExternalService>().As<IExternalService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

won't compile.
In other words, my app may be used from a customer who only communicates with External System A. In this configuration I want to include only the dlls from the core Project and External System A dll. If the customer is using B then only B will be included and so on.
Is that Possible?

Comment: This question is no clear. Are you talking about installers?

Comment: No, It's a web api application. There are no installers. The problem is that I need to upload my app on many servers for different customers. Customer A is using external System A, customer B is using external System B and so on. Using the current architecture I have to upload all dlls from all the external systems to all customers...

Comment: and why is this an issue? Put all dll's on all servers and control by config. I don't see an issue with what you already have?

Comment: It doesn't seem elegant. I was wondering whether there exists a better approach

Comment: But it's not broken? Why fix it? As far as I can tell adding a converluted complicated structure just so you don't have to ship an few extra kb of files seems over kill

Comment: If the number of external systems is small, then you are correct, there exists no problem, but if the the number is big, then there exists an issue

Comment: What issue? How does it actually cause a problem? I mean it's up to you but this seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using conditional statements could work.
Instead of this:

```
using Lib_ExtA;
using Lib_ExtB;
using Lib_General;
```

... use this:

```
#if UseExtA
using ExternalService = ExtA.ExternalService;
#endif
#if UseExtB
using ExternalService = ExtB.ExternalService;
#endif
#if UseGeneral
using ExternalService = General.ExternalService;
#endif
```

... followed by just:

```
this.RegisterType<ExternalService>().As<IExternalService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

You might combine this with the `switch` approach, giving an extra check if you did everything right, but it basically means you're doing it twice.

*References:*

> #if (C# Reference)
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

> /define (C# Compiler Options)
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx

Comment: I just realize that Project References may still make it hard or even impossible to achieve your goal. Perhaps deploying only what is needed will work, but you'll have to try to find that out.

Comment: This will still require the inclusion of all dll's (which I think is what the OP is getting at). BTW the pre-compiler optimises using statements so unused references are stripped out at compile time.